# Active Record Conditional Validation for password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a project that allows a user to invite another user by adding their email. When they add their email a User is created. However I am having some problems with skipping validations.

On the invitations I'd like to skip the password validation. As only the email is required. I'm using BCrypt and has_secure_password. Does anybody have any idea on how to skip this?

My invitations_controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(invite_params)
  if @user.save
    @user.create_invitation_digest
    @user.send_invitation_email
    flash[:success] = 'User invited'
    redirect_to new_invitation_path
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Unable to invite'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and my User model:

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, unless: :invited?
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
belongs_to :company

def invited?
 controller_name = 'invitations'
end
```

Comment: Try `validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true, unless: :invited?`

Comment: does not work because has_secure_password has pre-defined validations on validating password on create.

Comment: Hmm Try this `has_secure_password :validations => false` along with the above.

Comment: Yeah that works, however I obviously don't want has_secure_password to validate as false. Except on invited?

Comment: Please accept the answer if worked :)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be ***removing*** `has_secure_password` from the model and changing the validation on password like below.

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true, unless: :invited?
```

If you want the ***confirmation check on password*** which is provided by `has_secure_password`, then provide a password confirmation validation manually like below.

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

And you can write your own ***customized authentication*** like below if you want the authentication on password provided by `has_secure_password`.

```
def password=(password_str)
  @password = password_str
  self.password_salt   = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  self.password_digest = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password_str, password_salt)
end

def authenticate(password)
  password.present? && password_digest.present? && password_digest == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

Declare an attribute in model and set its value to true in controller. And do has_secured_password in model only if its value is false.

`user.rb`:

```
attr_accessor: skip_validation // Add this line
has_secured_password, :unless => :skip_validation  // Add IF condition here
```

`user_controller.rb`

```
def create
@user = User.new(invite_params)
@user.skip_validation = true // Add this line
  if @user.save
    @user.create_invitation_digest
    @user.send_invitation_email
    flash[:success] = 'User invited'
    redirect_to new_invitation_path
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Unable to invite'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: that results in an undefined local variable or method `skip_validation'